# I have a 5 V probe that needs to output 24 V. Can this be done?

Tags: voltage

I have a touch probe for a CNC.

[image]

It is 5 V, NPN  and NC. This is its wiring diagram:

[image]

My new CNC machine will only register a signal that is 22 V or higher, so I have the option of either buying a new probe for £300 or hopefully finding a way to convert/adjust this to make it work.

The machine has both a 5 V and a 24 V power supply to take from. Any solution would need to be fast. The probe moves and touches a surface. That touch generates a signal that the machine reads and tells it the location of a part down to 0.005 mm. Any delay in signal would affect accuracy. Though beggars maybe can't be choosers, unless I spend a further £300.

So can anyone suggest an answer and hopefully draw a circuit if it is possible?

I have soldering equipment and can do that side of things. I'm a complete novice on the electrical side so please explain things in laymans terms or better still with pictures.

Comment: Which limit for  VCC (on the OUT pin, not the 5V connected to the pin named VCC) is stated in the datasheet?

Comment: @asdfex I'm not sure but the manual with all the technical info is located https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RSx0s1y9xZ3yh1cPNFbuVpgiLJCMZFux/view?ts=603dff63 

thanks for your help so far :-)

Comment: Does the probe output just an on/off signal, or is it some kind of analog signal? The former is easy, the latter is still easy but slightly less so. Or is it a digital signal that needs bidirectional communication? That's slightly harder, but still doable.

Answer (score 1):

From the "5V version" section of the datasheet linked in the comments:

> Output function: electronic high-speed switch as (NPN-NC) normally
> close contact; switching up to 24V
>
> Switching current: max. 300 mA
>
> Operating voltage: 2 – 5,5V DC

So, the probe needs a 5V operating voltage on the VCC pin.
But the OUT pin can stand voltages up to 24V, so there is no issue using this probe in your setup. So, if you add the "optional" resistor in your setup (10 kOhm should be fine, resulting in a current of 2.4mA) and connect it to the 24V supply rail, your CNC machine should work as expected.

Comment: Hey that's brilliant. Thanks so much for that. Can I be a pain and ask you to clarify that in terms for a slight stupid oldish man :-) 

If it could be like my example below it would be amazing:

Brown wire 5v+
VCC 24+ before the resistor where it says VCC
white wire GND

Or even better, and only if you have time, if you could edit the picture. But only if you have time>
Super thanks any way so far.
Jools

Comment: @Jools Exactly. Note the difference between minor and capital letters in your drawing: Vcc and VCC: The brown wire connects Vcc to 5V.  On the green wire you have the OUT pin connected to the CNC and to a resistor. The resistors second pin (labeled VCC) goes to 24V.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.
How do I send you a pint :-)